# fscanf changes string variable?

Tags: c, variables, while-loop, scanf

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm currently learning C, but I've come across something that confuses me.

In my while loop i have:

```
char* bword = word
fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
```

Where word is a char[46], bword is a char* and fp is the file (a word dictionary in this case). I wanted to keep track of the word before it gets replaced when scanning fp. And it seemed logical to me to asign the word to a variable before it gets changed. But if I print bword after fscanf(fp, '%s", word) then it's changed to the new word! I don't really understand why and how.

If I do this:

```
bword = word;
printf("1.%s\n", word);
printf("2.%s\n", bword);
// scan the file for a for a word and store in word
fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
printf("3.%s\n", word);
printf("4.%s\n", bword);
```

I get these results in the command line:

```
1. 
2. 
3.a
4.a
```

(You don't see anything before 1 and 2 because the word was empty at the time).
I also tried assigning word to something "bar" before the loop but then I got:

```
1.bar
2.bar
3.a
4.a
```

So how do I solve this? I don't want bword to change.

Comment: You don't know anything about poitners, do you? please post the declarations of both `word` and `bword`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that this

```
char *bword = word;
```

declares a pointer to the first element of the array `word`, which means that modifiying `bword` modifies `word` too, because `bword` is just a reference<sup>1</sup> to the real data location which is the array `word`

If you want `bword` and `word` to be independent of each other then make `bword` an array so it's stored in a different location, like this

```
char bword[SOME_REASONABLE_SIZE];
```

from here you can call `fscanf()` and pass the appropriate array and the result will be the one you expected before.

Notice, that when you pass the array to `fscanf()`, essentially you are passing a pointer to the first element of it, just what your `bword` was in the first place.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>A reference in a general sense, not in c++ sense.</sub>

Comment: Oh great thank you, i totally overlooked that! It's great to get view from the outside sometimes. I solved the issue with strcpy(bword, word); and it works. Is that also a good use or is it bad habit?

Answer (score 0):

First you must learn about pointers (you can see [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)).
Then you find out array is a pointer to a memory so when you assigning them you just assign addresses so if one of them change other one is also changed. if you want to copy strings you can not assign then you must copy them and you can use `strcpy()` function. as it man page says it have following syntax:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

> The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest.  The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.  Beware of buffer overruns!

Comment: I bet you that the OP will do this `char *bword; strcpy(bword, word);` which isn't even close to what the OP needs and undefined behavior too, the pointers tutorial on the other hand is a good suggestion but you should not post **link only** answers, you can add that in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I new to stackoverflow and I think my answer is large enough to post it as answer, when I post it I see your good answer so sorry again.

Comment: You don't have to appologize, if you have the time you can make your answer better by addressing some of the other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the site Parham! will definitely read that. :) And iharob you're right, i did actually do strcpy(bword, word);  where bword is the same as my word (a char[46])